# Ansible trim/regex_replace getting false output

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I have some variable somevariable.stdout returns "no\n" like below in ansible playbook:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "no\n"
}
```

I have to remove \n from somevariable.stdout.

i tried below:

```
 - set_fact:
     remove: "{{ somevariable.stdout |  regex_replace(('\\n'), (''))}}"
```

I am getting false output and also tried trim tool  that is also getting false output.

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": false
}
```

Expected output:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "no"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `set_fact`, you can use `debug` and `register` to resolve your particular scenario as:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ somevariable.stdout | regex_replace('\n') }}"
  register: remove
- debug:
    msg: "{{ remove }}" #somevariable.stdout without '\n'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to use this remove variable globally

Comment: you can `export` the `register` variable and you can use the same globally.